# Update parent page on modal dialog close?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a window with a grid in it. This window has a button, when this button is pressed, a modal dialog is shown.

code:

```
    private void Edit_Click6S(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextEditWindow editWindow = new TextEditWindow();
        editWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When the user is finished with this dialog, the following code is called:

```
    Window.Close()
```

But the grid of the parent window is not updated. Is there a way to reinitialize the parent windows grid when the child dialog is closed? Is so, How?

Comment: How do you fill the grid in the first place? Can't you just call that method again after the `ShowDialog()`? `ShowDialog()` causes the code to 'pause' while the form is open, so antyhing you put after that will be ran after the child window closes.

Comment: Oh, I thought different windows ran on different threads! >_>

Comment: This is a [duplicate question][1].  But the short answer is to use delegates.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155543/what-is-the-best-practice-for-communicating-forms/7155596#comment8586265_7155596

Comment: 1) Do not Close() a Dialog, set its DialogResult property.

Comment: 2) Showing a Dialog or other Window does not involve threading. Update your data in the normal manner. Events and delegates should not be required.

Comment: @HankHolterman I agree with the dialog entry could be posted back to the database upon close, but you still need an event to trigger the update of the datagrid on the parent form.  Personally, I think delegates are the simplist and cleanest approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since dialogs block execution until they are closed, you can populate the grid directly after your `ShowDialog()` call:

```
private void Edit_Click6S(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextEditWindow editWindow = new TextEditWindow();
    editWindow.ShowDialog();
    PopulateGrid();
}
```

Otherwise you can handle the dialog's Closed event

```
editWindow.Closed += dialog_Closed;    

private void dialog_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateGrid();
}
```

Comment: Would be a better answer when DialogResult is checked (for not Canceled?)

Comment: To be honest I didn't notice the call back: editWindow.Closed += dialog_Closed;

So I repectfully recant. :) This will work. And it's cleaner than my approach if an event already exists.

Comment: Sorry, I actually only added that line a little later for additional clarity.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate my comment a little more; this is a common question and can be a bit confusing.  But use delegates to manage data between the forms.  Here is some code.  I can't promise it is ready to compile but it should help show you how to do this correctly.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void MenuClickedDelegate(); 
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       YourDialog yourDialog = new YourForm();
       yourDialog .MenuClickCallback = new MenuClickedDelegate(this.DoSomething);
       yourDialog .ShowDialog();
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Then for your dialog:

```
public partial class YourDialog  : Window
{
     public MainWindow.MenuClickedDelegate MenuClickCallback;
     public YourDialog()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void Edit_Click6S(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         this.close();
         MenuClickCallback;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why go to all this effort when there is already a `Closed` event firing?

Comment: This is a very strange way to use dialogs. Not directly wrong, just weird. And unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: If data is needed from the dialog, then it would be better to create a public property.  Then that property can be accessed on the main form after the dialog has been closed.  This way also means that you will not have a two-way dependency (as you have with the MenuClickedDelegate on the dialog).

Comment: You're right.  If the event already exsis this is a bit overkill, but it is a credible option.  Not sure it deserves the down vote.

Comment: Agreed, definitely still a viable option.